# mysql query optimization left join

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I m using following mysql query to fetch some desired result but problem is that it is taking more time. Currently execution time for this query is 7456 ms which is unacceptable for my project, I want to optimize this query any idea?.

```
 SELECT *, DATEDIFF(NOW(),ticketstatus_tbl.updation_date) AS problem_age,images_tbl.image_path
            FROM ticketstatus_tbl 
            LEFT JOIN question_tbl ON ticketstatus_tbl.question_id = question_tbl.question_id 
            LEFT JOIN ticketing_tbl ON ticketstatus_tbl.related_ticket_id = ticketing_tbl.ticket_id
            LEFT JOIN department_tbl ON question_tbl.question_dept = department_tbl.department_id
            LEFT JOIN branch_tbl ON ticketstatus_tbl.branch_id = branch_tbl.id
            LEFT JOIN images_tbl ON images_tbl.question_id = ticketstatus_tbl.question_id and images_tbl.branch_id = ticketstatus_tbl.branch_id
            WHERE (ticketstatus_tbl.ticket_status NOT IN ('Close')
            AND question_tbl.is_active_question = 1
            AND ticketstatus_tbl.display_status = '1'
            AND ticketstatus_tbl.flag_color = 'Yellow'
            AND department_tbl.department_name = 'Admin')order by ticket_number ASC LIMIT 0 ,5
```

Thanks

Comment: Please post the indexes you have on the tables and the explain for the query.

Comment: Table structure and EXPLAIN output, or don't expect meaningful answers. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/explain.html

Comment: Putting indexes on columns that are used in the ON clause usually helps a ton. Granted that you have no other weird things going on in the database. Which is why we probably need more info to help you out.

Answer (score 2):

First, you do not need all the `left outer join`, because your `where` clause is undoing most of them.  My guess is all could be turned into inner joins, but at the minimum:

```
SELECT *, DATEDIFF(NOW(),ticketstatus_tbl.updation_date) AS problem_age,images_tbl.image_path
FROM ticketstatus_tbl 
            JOIN question_tbl ON ticketstatus_tbl.question_id = question_tbl.question_id 
            LEFT JOIN ticketing_tbl ON ticketstatus_tbl.related_ticket_id = ticketing_tbl.ticket_id
            JOIN department_tbl ON question_tbl.question_dept = department_tbl.department_id
            LEFT JOIN branch_tbl ON ticketstatus_tbl.branch_id = branch_tbl.id
            LEFT JOIN images_tbl ON images_tbl.question_id = ticketstatus_tbl.question_id and images_tbl.branch_id = ticketstatus_tbl.branch_id
WHERE ticketstatus_tbl.ticket_status NOT IN ('Close')
            AND question_tbl.is_active_question = 1
            AND ticketstatus_tbl.display_status = '1'
            AND ticketstatus_tbl.flag_color = 'Yellow'
            AND department_tbl.department_name = 'Admin'
order by ticket_number ASC LIMIT 0 ,5;
```

Second, you are doing filtering on`ticketstatus_tbl`.  You should have a composite index on `ticketstatus_tbl(display_status, flag_color, ticket_status, question_id)`.  If you can, change the `ticket_status not in ('Close')` to an affirmative statement:  `ticket_status in (`Open`, 'In Progress', . . .)`.  This makes it easier to use the index.

This is a start.

Comment: grt:) Gordon your trick works actually problem was in images_tbl. it contains nearly 15,000 rows ans i was performing left join that was causing long execution time. now using  inner join with images_tbl  execution time downs to 300ms. Thanks

Comment: @DineshNagar If this answer solved your problem, please select it as the correct answer. If it did not or if you want to add to it, please add your own answer and select that as your preferred answer.